# If I use this code is it safe against XSS attacks?

Tags: angular, xss

I have following code. The first case (URL) int the transform method is to santize URL. I need this, because I have to display urls to call a SSRS Report.

Then I have a rich editor in my angular application. So my user can create comments, which are saved in HTML code in a database. So I want to display the comments rendered in HTML div tag in Angular. But I want to be sure, that there are no possibilities to make XSS attacks. So if I use this code in an Angular pipe am I secure against XSS attacks or not and are the other HTML tags rendered? I don't understand the official documentation of this in Angular (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer, https://angular.io/api/core/SecurityContext)

```
  transform(html: any, type: string) {
    let santizedHTML;
    switch (type) {
      case "URL": {
        santizedHTML = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, html);
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(santizedHTML);
        break;
      }
      case "HTML": {
        santizedHTML = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, html);
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(santizedHTML);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```